# Random Forest Classifier: Set feature importances?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

On a RFC model, I am trying to figure out how the feature importances change my classification when i am perturbing my data, like

features(no perturbation)= features(perturbed data)-features(perturbation)

Then using the features(no perturbation) on my already fit model.
Do you if it is possible to manually set or change the feature importances of an RFC model ? I tried looking for but no results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general convention in scikit-learn code is that attributes that are inferred from your data / training end with **_**. *feature_importances_* attributes respects that convention as well. They represent impurity-based importances and they are computed / inferred from your training set statistics.

You have the option to act on the weight you give to the different samples through *sample_weight* argument as well as weighting your classes through *class_weight* parameter.

Comment: hmm i see, thank you ! I ill try something then.